# Inicia una app desde un un fragment

Tags: android

Tengo una *app* que lanza una notificacion y otra *app* que la recoge. El problema es que la actividad que recoge el `intent` quiero que no se inicialize en una `activity` como siempre sino quiero que lo haga en un `fragment`. ¿Saben de alguna forma? Gracias

Comment: Pero un fragment siempre se encuentra dentro un activity por lo tanto debes iniciar la activity donde se encuentra dicho fragment

Answer (score 2):

Tiene que iniciar en una Actividad (`FragmentActivity`) ya que esta es la que puede contener el `Fragment`, un `Fragment` no puede estar aislado de una Activity.

Simplemente realiza la transacción del `Fragment` que deseas al iniciar en el método `onCreate()` del FragmentActivity.

```
              // Carga nuevo fragmento deseado mediante una transacción.
              Fragment nuevoFragmento = new myFragment();
              FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
              transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nuevoFragmento);
              transaction.addToBackStack(null);
              // Commit a la transacción
              transaction.commit();
```